# Loss of quotes when encoding into ascii

Tags: python, regex, utf-8, ascii

I wish to extract the text between quotations from news articles. For this purpose the first step involves extracting the new articles. Then in the second step using a regex to get the quotations. I am not sure but the quotations get lost when I encode into ascii. Is there a way around this?

```
from goose import Goose
from requests import get

response = get('http://www.nytimes.com/2015/05/19/health/study-finds-dense-breast-tissue-isnt-always-a-high-cancer-risk.html?src=me&ref=general')
extractor = Goose()
article = extractor.extract(raw_html=response.content)
text = article.cleaned_text
encode_text=text.encode('ascii','ignore')
comments=re.findall('"([^"]*)"', encode_text)
print comments
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of brute-force destroying everything, use [Unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) to transliterate the text into ASCII.

```
>>> unidecode.unidecode(u'“…”')
'"..."'
```

Comment: Can provide a example of the usage please.

Comment: From the page:
`>>> from unidecode import unidecode`
`>>> unidecode(u'ko\u017eu\u0161\u010dek')`
`'kozuscek'`
`>>> unidecode(u'30 \U0001d5c4\U0001d5c6/\U0001d5c1')`
`'30 km/h'`
`>>> unidecode(u"\u5317\u4EB0")`
`'Bei Jing '`

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Why don't you add an example to your answer.